# How are DDOS protection mechanisms setup when confidential data is involved?

Tags: ddos, sensitive-data-exposure, cloudflare

**Scenario:**

A hospital has the records of all patients. There is an online portal where patients can login to see their personal medical data.

Since a hospital is an obvious target for any type of hack, the hospital decides to implement DDoS protection. Using providers like Cloudflare, would have this personal data flow *unencrypted* over at least part of the path from the hospital and the patient. This is undesirable considering the nature of the data being transported.

**Question:** How would a hospital (or a similar institute which is likely a target and holds personal data on scale) implement a DDoS which would make sure the data is encrypted from the hospital to the patient and back?

Comment: You are working under a false understanding. There are lots of ways to do DDoS protection that do not require unencrypted data. And I think you have a misunderstanding about Cloudflare. Cloudflare needs unencrypted data for its CDN service. But even that isn't required. You can use Cloudflare without a CDN and encrypting every hop.